# Beautifulsoup extracking attribute TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I used to get tag attributes by this

```
for a in soup.find_all('img', {'data-event': 'Clicked image'}, 
src=True,alt=True):
    itemobj = a['src'] + ' --- ' + a['alt']
```

Now I am working on another site and When I tried this it threw TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

```
 song_link = line.find('td').find('a')['href'] (This works well)
 sss = line.find('span')['title'] (This in not working. But when I delete ['title'] part it works and shows inside of the <span> tag
```

My data:

```
<span class="rating" title="4.5">
          <span class="icon-rating-sm icon-rating-sm__active"></span>
          <span class="icon-rating-sm icon-rating-sm__active"></span>
          <span class="icon-rating-sm icon-rating-sm__active"></span>
          <span class="icon-rating-sm icon-rating-sm__active"></span>
          <span class="icon-rating-sm icon-rating-sm__half"></span>
 </span>
```

I have been searching solution to this but so far none of them worked for me.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What have you stored in `line` variable? Is it the data you published?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost three years passed since this extremely unclear question and I somehow forgot about it up until today. I saw that this question reached quite a few people and I would like to give my input which I believe **definitely** resolve the problem in your code.

Unfortunately, I do not remember the problem I had with my code and all the things I have written are very unclear. However, I do have a couple of ideas what might have caused the problem. And here are my suggestions for you.

**1. Read the documentation carefully:**

BeaututifulSoup has a very well written documentation if you do not know how to use selectors and looking for a lazy answer, just like I did, I would highly recommend you to take a look at the BS4 documentation located here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/# (Especially read the selectors as the most problems caused by the misuse of CSS selectors). Instead of searching for an answer for 5 minutes spend 10 minutes and learn how it works. I promise you that will be much more beneficial for you.

**2. Make sure you have the correct object**

By running `print(dir(your_object))` you can see all methods that your object can run. Furthermore, whenever you are stuck try to debug the code and try to find the mistake. At the time I was using IDLE editor but recently I realised that VS Code has a built-in [Python debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) which is **very useful** and it can and will solve your problem 99% of the time.

**3. Make sure you got the correct item**

As @Friedrich Staufenbiel pointed out most likely my data contained an extra `<span>` element like below

```
<span></span>
<span class="rating" title="4.5">
    <span class="icon-rating-sm icon-rating-sm__active"></span>
    <span class="icon-rating-sm icon-rating-sm__active"></span>
    <span class="icon-rating-sm icon-rating-sm__active"></span>
    <span class="icon-rating-sm icon-rating-sm__active"></span>
    <span class="icon-rating-sm icon-rating-sm__half"></span>
</span>
```

This is most likely what caused the problem however, I would like to point out that I was looking for a `<span>` element in the `line` variable, which is most likely an element of a list with a for a loop iteration. And in that case, it is expected for the program to crash as not all have the `<span>` element. The best thing you can do is to put the part of the code which cause the problem in a `try-except` block like this

```
try:
    sss = line.find('span')['title']
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

At least this way you can find the part of the code which causes the program to crash and you can give the error messages to other people so that they can help you better.

I am 100% sure that you will resolve whatever problem you are having if you follow the things I mentioned above, besides they are good engineering practices which you should have anyway. A special thanks for @Friedrich Staufenbiel and @matusf for their kind attention.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried your code on the data you provided it worked fine for me so I am going to assume that there is more data to this.

```
soup.find('span')['title']
```

checks the first thing it finds with "span", if this doesn't contain a title tag it throws an exception.

e.g. on

```
<span></span>
<span class="rating" title="4.5">
      <span class="icon-rating-sm icon-rating-sm__active"></span>
      <span class="icon-rating-sm icon-rating-sm__active"></span>
      <span class="icon-rating-sm icon-rating-sm__active"></span>
      <span class="icon-rating-sm icon-rating-sm__active"></span>
      <span class="icon-rating-sm icon-rating-sm__half"></span>
</span>
```

the code doesn't work.

At least this is what happened to me a couple times.